# Set currenttime on html5 audio player with link

Tags: html, audio, youtube, timestamp

Does anyone know how to set the currentTime property of html5 audio by clicking a link with a time? Similar to how Youtube does it? Say I click a link "3:10", it will instantly change the currently playing audio's currentTime to 3:10.

```
<audio controls loop class="sound">
    <source src="../../site/music/music1.mp3"/>
    <source src="../../site/music/music2.ogg"/>
</audio>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b><a>3:10</a></b> consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just use the *currentTime* Property of the  or  tag.

**Notes:** 
- The current time is set in seconds not minutes. so 3:10 means second 190.
- You should give an ID for your Audio/Video example:

```
<audio id="myAud" controls loop class="sound"> 
<a href="#" onClick="{myAud.currentTime=190;}">Set CurTime</a>
```